# Dealing with Adobe popups

Tags: protractor

Is it possible to detect Adobe update popups and get rid of them with protractor? I have some tests on Sauce Labs that consistently fail in IE8 and IE10 as Adobe is updated. See attached screenshot for an example. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, *you cannot control this kind of system-level popups with Protractor/Selenium*. I would contact Sauce Labs support to ask how to turn the Adobe Acrobat Reader auto-update off when launching a new machine for testing.